# How To Consume a WCF service in PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, wcf, soap

I have a simple WCF Service running with a GET function.
When I call it in a web browser. It works fine.

When I try the following PHP call:

```
define('NEWLINE' , "< br />\n");
$wsdl = "https://www.***.info/Webservices/WCF/***.svc?wsdl";
Line 727: $soapClient= new SoapClient($wsdl,array('cache_wsdl' => 0));
$result = $soapClient->TestForPHP();
$soapClient = null;
echo "WCF service Return value: "." "."($result->getMessageResult)". NEWLINE;
```

I get the following error in my debug:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Could not find any usable binding services in WSDL. in /home/customer/www/staging9.***.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/hello-theme-child-master/functions.php:727
```

Here is what my bindings look like in my web.config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
 
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="inculdeExceptionDetails">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true " />
        </behavior>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="https">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

This webservice is in use being successfully consumed by other .NET clients, but this is my first attempt at doing it with PHP.
I have also just tested and it works in jquery (which for now I will work with).
I honestly, do not understand my binding settings though I remember that I did struggle to set it up to work properly for my .NET clients

Comment: Not sure if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157837/could-not-find-any-usable-binding-services-in-wsdl is the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The binding used by your WCF service is webHttpBinding, so it is not correct to use soapClient to call the wcf service. You need to construct an HTTP request to access your WCF service.You can refer to this link to construct HTTP requests to access WCF services:[HTTP Request](https://github.com/php-http/documentation/blob/master/components/client-common.rst)